# How do you prevent <br> tags from displaying in textarea?

Tags: php, html, sql

I am saving this string into my sql db:

```
   $receipt.= "$tempQty $tempItem : $tempColor :<br> 
                        $tempService <br>
                        &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp Item Total: $$tempPrice 
                        <br><br>";
```

This displays fine in a table:

```
3 Pants : White

Hem: $50.00
Press: $65.00

Item Total: $115.00
```

But when I display it in a textarea it shows up like this:

```
3 Pants : White <br>
                        Hem: $50.00
Press: $65.00 <br> 
                        Item Total: $115.00 <br><br>
```

How can I get the textarea to keep the formatting but not show the `<br>` tags.

Comment: _"I am saving this string into my sql db"_ - well there's your mistake ... You should not _store_ the data this way to begin with, but store actual line break characters. And then you apply `nl2br` when this value gets _output_ into the page to display with line breaks; and as originally stored in the database, when you want to populate the textarea. (Applying `htmlspecialchars` might still be a good idea in both cases.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to strip out the `<br>` tags and the extra space. Here's a way to do it by splitting the array by `<br>`, trimming the array parts, then joining it back together with `\n`.

```
<?php
$receipt = explode("<br>", $receipt);
foreach ($receipt as $n => $r) $receipt[$n] = trim($r);
$receipt = implode("\n", $receipt);
?>    

<textarea cols='60' rows='8'><?php echo $receipt;?></textarea>
```

Comment: That got rid of the <br> tags, but I still have this weird spacing: 

3 Pants : White 

      Hem: $50.00
Press: $65.00 
 
      Item Total: $115.00

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: That worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the 
 with `&#13;&#10;&#13;&#10;`

Line Feed and 
 Carriage Return are HTML entitieswikipedia. This way you are actually parsing the new line ("\n") rather than displaying it as text.

Example:

```html
    <textarea cols='60' rows='8'>3 Pants : White one.&#13;&#10;&#13;&#10;Hem: $50.00</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$textarea = str_replace('<br>', '\n\r', $textarea);
```

Comment: Oops, yes, thank you! I edited it.